# Hiding bubble label on google bubble charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm working with Google Charts API to display a bubble chart. Everything is working fine except that the labels on the individual bubbles gets kind of annoying when the bubbles are close together. I really just want to hide the labels but can't seem to find an option to do it. Has anyone worked with google bubble charts and knows how to hide the label?

Comment: I found the answer to this.  There is an option for the bubble text in options.   bubble: {textStyle: {color: 'none'}}

Comment: Or set the 'trigger' to 'none': var options = { tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },

Comment: bubble: {textStyle: {color: 'none'}} works, thanks. Still, the example by google charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#options) hide only the labels that do not fit. This is even nicer. However, the chart options of the example do not have anything specific, and if I copy the code it shows all labels, not just the ones that fit...

Answer (score 7):

If you set the first column of the data table to a blank string then you won't have this information in the tooltips either.

An alternative is to keep the strings and set `bubble.textStyle.color = "transparent"`

Comment: Alternatively you can also set `bubble: {textStyle: {color: 'none'}}` in your options. https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=803

Answer (score 1):

Set the values in the first column (ID) to a blank string. See the documentation, second example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart